# Why is my ASP.NET MVC application trying to navigate to login.aspx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have a very very simple, "Hello World" level application that I built in ASP.NET MVC 4 / Razor.  It works fine in debug mode.  There is no authentication; it just goes straight to Home/Index.

Now I published it to IIS.  But when I view it through IIS, for some reason it's trying to load a "login.aspx" form.  I have not defined any such form, not in web.config, not anywhere else in the system.  And no matter what path I put in the URL, it always redirects to the non-existent login.apsx.

WHY?  How do I fix it?

**EDIT:** Per requests by commenters, here's my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
      <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
      <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-AdminBackdoor-20130314103822;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-AdminBackdoor-20130314103822.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyProjectEntities.csdl|res://*/MyProjectEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyProjectEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyProject;Integrated Security=True; ;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None">
      <!--<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />-->
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    <legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" />
    <settings>
      <!-- This setting causes .NET to check certificate revocation lists (CRL) 
                 before trusting HTTPS certificates.  But this setting tends to not 
                 be allowed in shared hosting environments. -->
      <!--<servicePointManager checkCertificateRevocationList="true"/>-->
    </settings>
  </system.net>
  <dotNetOpenAuth>
    <messaging>
      <untrustedWebRequest>
        <whitelistHosts>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable communication with localhost (should generally not activate in production!) -->
          <!--<add name="localhost" />-->
        </whitelistHosts>
      </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
    <openid>
      <relyingParty>
        <security requireSsl="false">
          <!-- Uncomment the trustedProviders tag if your relying party should only accept positive assertions from a closed set of OpenID Providers. -->
          <!--<trustedProviders rejectAssertionsFromUntrustedProviders="true">
                        <add endpoint="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud" />
                    </trustedProviders>-->
        </security>
        <behaviors>
          <!-- The following OPTIONAL behavior allows RPs to use SREG only, but be compatible
                         with OPs that use Attribute Exchange (in various formats). -->
          <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
        </behaviors>
      </relyingParty>
    </openid>
  </dotNetOpenAuth>
  <uri>
    <!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
             which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name.
             It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
    <idn enabled="All" />
    <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could there be a parent website in IIS from which your application might be inheriting web.config settings?

Comment: Is Allow Anonymous switched on in IIS > Authorization Rules?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - why would it?  There's a web.config in the root folder of the website.  (Anyway, no, there's no parent web.config.)

Comment: @Oliver - all users allowed.  I added "Allow Anonymous" explicitly, just to be sure; still doesn't work.

Comment: web.config settings are inherited. So if you have some parent website that's where the `login.aspx` could be coming from.

Comment: Do you have any <authentication> settings in your web.config?  If it's fine in debug mode, check for transform elements in the web.release.config file.

Comment: @Oliver - No, I commented out the "authentication" settings.

Comment: Rather than commenting them out, try setting the authentication mode="None", then any parent config will not be inherited as @DarinDimitrov noted.

Comment: @Oliver - done.  Still redirects to login.aspx

Comment: @Shaul please show the web.cofig setups and the IIS settings. so that other can help you out. rather than discussing in comments

Comment: @Ravi - added web.config.  What part of IIS settings do you want to see?

Comment: @Oliver - problem solved.  Close to what you suggested, but just one off... see my answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - courtesy ping: problem solved

Comment: @Ravi - courtesy ping: problem solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, the horror and the shame.  "Anonymous Users" was allowed in IIS under "Authorization Rules"... but "Anonymous Authentication" was disabled under "Authentication".

I'll get over my embarrassment and not delete this question for the sake of future programmers who may benefit from this...

Comment: Thanks for this! I had the same issue although I don't ever remember changing this in IIS.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else comes upon this, there is another potential solution as described in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285186/acs-installed-but-mvc-4-0-app-still-redirects-and-fails-to-find-login-aspx). Remove the WebMatrix DLLs from your bin directory.

It is possible that this problem arises if you use "Add Deployable Dependencies" from VS 2010. That includes the WebMatrix stuff, which in turn blows up your authentication under certain circumstances. In that case, remove WebMatrix from the _bin_deployableAssemblies directory, which will in turn keep it out of bin when you build or deploy.

Comment: You, you deserve something special for this.

Comment: Deleting the WebMatrix DLLs did it for me. Thanks :)